# Unable to remove file Ionic 2 - Code 6 (NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR)

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 on my Android (7.1.2) device and getting code 6 when I use the removeFile method of the ionic-native file object. I have `permission` to write on external storage.

I'm calling the method this way: 
this.file.removeFile(path, this.entries[i].name)

**Where path is:** 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/melodies/E/'

and this.entries[i].name is: '500hz.wav'

The file exists in path. I've tried to use the method "`moveFile`" to make a logical deletion but it returns the same '`No Modification Allowed Error`'.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and I have managed to solve it by modifying the code of the media-capture plugin. Now all the videos are saved in the internal memory and I have no problems deleting them. I hope it serves you and it's not too late. You can see my repo [here](https://github.com/sergiomedinavalentin/cordova-plugin-media-capture).

```
private void captureVideo(Request req) {
    if(cameraPermissionInManifest && !PermissionHelper.hasPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        PermissionHelper.requestPermission(this, req.requestCode, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    } else {
        File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", req.duration);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality", req.quality);
        }
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, req.requestCode);
    }
}
```